# What exactly does the collocation "pull the vote" mean?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, parliament, cabinet

Does it mean to give up and not organize the voting? Is there an opposite such as push (for) the vote? (I am an English learner/translator.)

This is a context: "A ring-round of Cabinet on Friday and over the weekend saw ministers more or less unanimous: the vote should be pulled. The press became increasingly confident that May could not go ahead: in the Sunday Times on 9 December, Tim Shipman predicted that it would be pulled." (May at 10 - Anthony Seldon)

It is used in [this article](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-48360456) too.

Comment: I believe the meaning here is [definition 6: to remove from a place or situation or to revoke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull) – that is, they're planning to cancel the scheduled vote. For questions on language, though, you'd do better to ask them on [english.se] or [ell.se]

Comment: The question is about the meaning of a phrase in political reporting. While there might be overlap with English-language.SE it is a question about political process.

Answer (score 5):

It is the Oxford English Dictionary's, sense 10(b) of the verb *to pull*.

Essentially it means "put a stop to something*. It is said to be of *US origin*s, and the first OED example from the *Baltimore Sun* in 1937. Though it wasn't in that instance, it is often applied to the stopping of a newspaper report or publication.

> *10. b. transitive. colloquial (originally U.S.). To withdraw from publication, circulation, or use; to cancel or revoke (a business
> deal, etc.); to recall or rescind (a document); to cease to operate or
> make use of.
>
> 1937   Sun (Baltimore) 22 May 18/3   We are pulling the fires under
> most of the boilers but leaving sufficient boilers to maintain steam
> to [etc.].
>
> 1967   Los Angeles Times 15 Jan. g4/4   Staughton Lynd of Yale made an
> unauthorized trip to North Vietnam in 1965, and the department pulled
> his passport.
>
> 1978   G. Bordman Amer. Musical Theatre ii. 96   Previous commitments
> forced it to be pulled when its initial booking ended.
>
> 1986   Times 11 Oct. 21/5   Some dealers were convinced the deal had
> been pulled at the last minute after a disagreement over the price.
>
> 2005   Gazette (Montreal) (Nexis) 12 Mar. a7   The Gazette has joined
> several other newspapers that have decided to pull any further Julie
> story ads.*